# Import Z3 model value to C++

Tags: c++, z3

I'm writing some code to generate constraints for Z3 and then solve for results. I can print out the result by the command `Z3_model_to_string(ctx,m)` and the result shows `x1-> 1 x2->100` where x1 and x2 are both int. My question is how I can save these integer values into C++ variables for future analysis?

Here is the part of code I wrote for Z3

```
Z3_model m;
context ctx;
Z3_ast fs;
string str = "(declare-const x1 Int) (assert (> x1 0)) (declare-const x2 Int) (assert (not (< x2 100)))" //Generated by some other function
fs  = Z3_parse_smtlib2_string(Z3_context(ctx), str, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Z3_assert_cnstr(Z3_context(ctx), fs);
Z3_lbool result = Z3_check_and_get_model(Z3_context(ctx), &m);
switch (result) {
case Z3_L_FALSE:
    printf("unsat\n");
    break;
case Z3_L_UNDEF:
    printf("unknown\n");
    printf("potential model:\n%s\n", Z3_model_to_string(Z3_context(ctx), m));
    break;
case Z3_L_TRUE:
    printf("sat\n%s\n", Z3_model_to_string(Z3_context(ctx), m));
    break;
}
int num_constants = Z3_get_model_num_constants(Z3_context(ctx), m);
model aaa(ctx,m);
for (i = 0; i< num_constants; i++) {
    z3::expr r = aaa.get_const_interp(aaa.get_func_decl(i));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have a model `m`, you can use the get_const_intrp and get_func_interp functions in class model to obtain their values. For the case of simple integer variables there should be `n` constants (i.e., constant functions) in the model, i.e., `m.num_consts()` = `n` and

```
expr r = m.get_const_interp(m.get_const_decl(i));
```

will return the interpretation of the `i`-th constant in the model. For the case of simple integer constraints, the result will usually be an `expr` describing a numeric value, i.e., `r.is_numeral()` should be true. We can get different representations of those model values through these functions:

for integers and other types:

```
Z3_get_numeral_string
Z3_get_numeral_decimal_string
Z3_get_numeral_int
Z3_get_numeral_uint
Z3_get_numeral_uint64
Z3_get_numeral_int64
```

for real/rational numbers:

```
Z3_get_numeral_small
Z3_get_numerator
Z3_get_denominator
Z3_get_numeral_rational_int64
```

where the last part of the name indicates what type of object will be returned. Note that these functions will return `false` if the model values don't fit into the return type (e.g., number too large for the int range). If all model values are expected to be small, we can of course use these functions. The safe (and slow) way is to ask for a string and then convert it whatever big-integer representation you use for your application.

Note: The C++ API is only a thin layer on top of the C API and those two APIs are meant to be used together. Many functions only exist on the C layer and C++ objects like asts and exprs should convert automatically into the right kind of pointers for the C API.

Here is a complete example for this particular case. I took the liberty of rewriting some of the code in a more C++ like style:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <z3++.h>
using namespace z3;

void main() {
    try {        
        context ctx;        
        Z3_string str = "(declare-const x1 Int) (assert (> x1 0)) (declare-const x2 Int) (assert (not (< x2 100)))"; //Generated by some other function
        expr fs(ctx, Z3_parse_smtlib2_string(Z3_context(ctx), str, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));

        solver s(ctx);
        s.add(fs);
        check_result cr = s.check();

        model aaa(ctx, s.get_model());
        int num_constants = aaa.num_consts();
        for (int i = 0; i < num_constants; i++) {
            func_decl fd = aaa.get_const_decl(i);
            z3::expr r = aaa.get_const_interp(fd);
        }
    }
    catch (z3::exception e) {
        std::cout << e.msg() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here might be a stupid question. The type of `m` is **Z3_model** as I used C API, I tried `int num = m.get_const_int()` but g++ reported `get_const_int is of non-class type of Z3_model{aka _Z3_model*}`. Do I have to do the conversion between **model** in C++ API and **Z3_model** in C API manually?

Comment: Another thing I want to ask is by using `Z3_get_numeral_int`, I have to pass an ast parameter which I guess should be coming from Z3_model m. Is there any way to obtain ast from the model?

Comment: The C++ API has a class called 'model' and the C API has a type called Z3_model. The C++ class has an operator that automatically converts 'model' to 'Z3_model', but not the other way around. However, you can construct a model from a Z3_model, i.e., model(ctx, m)

Comment: Every expr is an ast (in the C++ API you can see that expr is derived from ast). get_numeral_int takes the C-equivalent, i.e., a Z3_ast. In C++ this conversion should be automatic through the conversion operator defined in class ast. get_const_interp gets the corresponding interpretation in the model, which is an expr (and therefore an ast as well). The result from Z3_get_numeral_int is a Z3_ast already.

Comment: I tried creating C++ context and converting to C Z3_context and then solving for the results. g++ complained **class z3::model has no member named get_num_consts()** so I used `z3_get_model_num_constants(Z3_context(ctx),m)` instead. While trying to execute `expr r = m.get_const_interp(m.get_func_decl(i));` terminal says **terminate called after throwing an instance of z3::exception** and then aborted. I've uploaded related code to the question part. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Ah! Sorry, in class model, get_num_consts() is just called num_consts() and get_func_decl is only for non-consts, the right function is called get_const_decl. I'll fix my answer and add an example.

Comment: What does the ordering here refer to? The order they were constructed?  I am using the C_API.  I'm using `mk_const` to create a constant and I just want to get a model from that constant but it seems the api calls for getting an interpretation want  `func_decl`.  Is there a function to convert between the two?

Comment: Nothing should be assumed about the order of model values inside a model, instead always refer to the func_decl associated with the index (get_const_decl(i)).  Const's and func_decl's are not the same thing, so there's no real "conversion", but the two are closely related: A const is an application of a constant function (to 0 arguments), so Z3_is_app will return true. The function being applied has a declaration like all other functions and that declaration can be obtained via Z3_get_app_decl. The resulting func_decl is then used to get the corresponding model value (via get_const_interp).